Why is it harder to prove lower bounds on expected maxima (than upper bounds)?
I am currently learning upper and lower bounds for the expected maxima of random variables, e.g. bounds for the quantity:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i\right]
$$
Most of the presentation comes from the books of Vershynin (High Dimensional Probability), and Wainwright (High Dimensional Statistics).
For upper bounds, there are a number of bounds that apply to generic Subgaussian processes (what that means specifically maybe isn't super relevant to my question, but the point is that there are somewhat generic bounds that work for a wide variety of distributions with certain growth conditions and no independence assumptions.) For example, Dudley's inequality or the generic chaining technique.
However, for lower bounds there is a stark contrast: all results in these books are only for Gaussian processes, e.g. in the above, the $X_i$ are assumed to have some joint Gaussian distribution with some covariance matrix. This seems like a very restrictive assumption and the proofs all use Kahane's Gaussian interpolation technique which doesn't seem to have a generic/non-gaussian analog.
My (possibly very silly) question is: Why is it the case that upper bounds  are easier to prove than lower bounds, for something like a running maximum? My admittedly uncalibrated intuition tells me a quantity like a maximum should be "large", so it should be "easy" to show lower bounds. Is it the lack of a union bound that causes issues? Many of the proofs of upper bounds seem to be (very refined) union bounds in some sense.

Simply because of the fact that, to obtain an upper bound on the quantity $\max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_i$, it is sufficient to identify quantities that are greater than or equal to each and every $X_i$. Such a quantity would be an upper bound on the $\max$, too.
However, to obtain a valid lower bound, it is not analogously necessary that that lower bound is less than or equal to each and every $X_i$ (it is sufficient, but not necessary). A quantity that is less than or equal to at least one $X_i$ would still be a valid lower bound on $\max$.
Due to this reason, the upper bounds on $\max$ are more likely to turn out to be sharp, but the same is not the case for the lower bounds. This makes it trickier to obtain sharp lower bounds on $\max$.
